# Removing characters from both dictionary's keys and values?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, strip

I am working on a routine to remove the periods `'.'` from a dictionary that gets dynamically built during a web-scrape.  Below is the code I am using which seems to work properly to remove the periods of the dictionary values (`y`) but not the keys (`x`).

Any guidance on how to solve this problem?

```
def dot_be_gone(dirty_dic):
    clean_dic = {}
    for x,y in dirty_dic.items():
        clean_x = str(x).strip('.')
        clean_y = str(y).strip('.')
        clean_dic[clean_x] = clean_y
    return(clean_dic)

dot_be_gone({"No. of Pets":"1", "No Problem":"Okay..."})
```

This results in the following when executed:

```
{'No. of Pets': '1', 'No Problem': 'Okay'}
```

As you can see the periods are removed from the 2nd value but not from the first key.

Comment: `strip` only removes characters from the start and end of the string. Use `replace`.

Answer (score 6):

[`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) only trim chars from start & end, use [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) instead

```
x = {'No. of Pets': '1', 'No Problem': 'Okay...'}

{k.replace('.', '') : v.replace('.', '') for k, v in x.items()}
```

> {'No of Pets': '1', 'No Problem': 'Okay'}

Answer (score 1):

By following your algorithm, I come up with a solution.

> **Method 1:** a naive way using the method *strip*

```
def dot_be_gone(dirty_dic):
    clean_dic = {}
    for x, y in dirty_dic.items():
        clean_x = x
        clean_y = y
        if '.' in x:
            x_items = x.split('.')
            clean_x = x_items[0] + x_items[1]
        if '.' in y:
            y_items = y.split('.')
            clean_y = y_items[0] + y_items[1]
        clean_dic[clean_x] = clean_y
    return(clean_dic)

x = dot_be_gone({"No. of Pets":"1", "No Problem":"Okay..."})
print(x) # {'No of Pets': '1', 'No Problem': 'Okay'}
```

> **Method 2:** using the method *replace*

```
def dot_be_gone(dirty_dic):
    clean_dic = {}
    for x, y in dirty_dic.items():
        clean_x = x.replace('.', "")
        clean_y = y.replace('.', "")
        clean_dic[clean_x] = clean_y
    return(clean_dic)

x = dot_be_gone({"No. of Pets":"1", "No Problem":"Okay..."})
print(x) # {'No of Pets': '1', 'No Problem': 'Okay'}
```

Comment: why not use `.replace`? This solution is over-engineered. It also assumes that there is only ever one `'.'` in the strings... Also, why keep the `strip('.')` lines??? In a branch where they'll never do anything. And why the extraneous calls to `str`???

Comment: It is also possible to use the method `replace`. Above, @zamir use this method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactely why that don't work but you can use the .replace method which uses str to replace in first arg and str to put at the place of the removed str in second arg So that gives :

```
 clean_x = x.replace(".", "")
 clean_y = y.replace(".", "")
```